# Is tertiary-butyl same as neo-butyl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, isomers

By definition neoalkanes have two-times branching of methylgroup at second last carbon.

But in no book which I could find, it is not alternatively named as neo-butyl.

Is the definition right, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the source of your definition? As you define neo, it seems to me you would need a minimum of 5 carbons. "Neo-butane", aka isobutane, has only one methyl branch from C2 of propane.

Comment: @user55119 but that is what I learnt in lecture.Can you please provide a better definition.

Comment: There is no neo-butane. Only two isomers of butane are known : n-butane, and isobutane (or méthylpropane). The 2,2-dimethylpropane you are mentioning is not a butane. it has 5 C atoms. I must nevertheless mention that your question is not related to its title. In the title you speak of butyl. In the text you speak of butane.

Comment: Thanks. Thank you. Question's description now corrected.

Comment: Neo is a trivial prefix, which in the context of hydrocarbons, means two carbons bound to  the same carbon (geminal) of the longest chain. The only hydrocarbon that commonly uses neo is neopentane. 2,2-Dimethylbutane could be called neohexane but I have never heard it. After neopentane, the nomenclature gets too complicated. By then, IUPAC nomenclature prevails.

Answer (score 5):

The prefix *neo-* is only used with pentane. It has a historical origin. In the $19$th century, the first $\ce{C_5H_{12}}$ that has been discovered was our *n*-pentane. At that time it was simply called pentane. After some time, a second $\ce{C_5H_{12}}$ was discovered. Today we know that it is methylbutane. As it was an isomer of pentane, the chemists decided to name it *iso*-pentane, without knowing exactly its structure. Later on a third $\ce{C_5H_{12}}$ was obtained in the lab, which is presently known as dimethylpropane. Here they had no idea about the way of naming it correctly. That is why somebody proposed to create the prefix *neo-*. This proposition was accepted with enthusiasm. Anyway the nature of the isomers was a puzzle at this time. So these isomers were intensely studied and their structure became slowly explained. This is why it was not necessary to use these prefixes (*iso*-, *neo*-, and maybe others - who knows?) for describing the numerous hexane and heptane isomers.